# Eclipse plugin, where in the editor did the popup menu happen?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing an eclipse plugin for a domain specific language. I've subclassed editor and things are working fine.

I'd like to add a popup menu so that I can do my own refactorings. I've used org.eclipse.ui.popupmenus to add the popupmenu, which when you right click on the editor, does provide the menu, it can be clicked, and the click executes the following method:

```
  public void run(IAction action) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "SyntaxColoringCSharp", "refactorA was executed.");
  }
```

My problem is that I don't know where in the editor the click happened - so it's difficult for me to get the right bit of the file to perform the refactoring on.  The cursor doesn't move to where the click happened.

How do I find out where in the editor the popupmenu click happened? (i.e. how do the Java refactoring get this information?)

Here is the basic class I'm working with:

```
package arteditor.popup.actions;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor;

import editoractions.EditorActions;

public class refactorA implements IObjectActionDelegate {

  private Shell shell;

  /**
   * Constructor for Action1.
   */
  public refactorA() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * @see IObjectActionDelegate#setActivePart(IAction, IWorkbenchPart)
   */
  public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
    shell = targetPart.getSite().getShell();
  }

  /**
   * @see IActionDelegate#run(IAction)
   */
  public void run(IAction action) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "SyntaxColoringCSharp", "refactorA was executed.");
  }

  /**
   * @see IActionDelegate#selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)
   */
  public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {

   }
}
```

Comment: It is normal to use the cursor (caret) position for the right click action - that is what the Java refactoring does in the Java editor context menu.

Comment: Son of a gun, so it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal to use the cursor (caret) position for the right click action - that is what the Java refactoring does in the Java editor context menu.

The `StyledText` widget has various methods to return the caret position.